# Django: {% csrf_token %} keeps returning 403 Forbidden error

Tags: python, django, django-csrf

I have a form that I try to submit however whenever I click the submit button Django puts me into the 403 Forbidden page error. I have no clue how to fix this. Please help. This is done using materialize CSS.

page.html:

```
<form action="/present/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %} 
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="completed" name="completed" />  
        <label for="completed">Present</label>
    </p>
        <input class="waves-effect waves-light btn" type='submit'/>

</form>
```

views.py:

```
def present(request):
    completed = request.GET.get('pre')
    if request.POST.get('completed', '') == 'on':
        print("Succes!")
    else:
        print("Nope")
    #above coode doesn't work either for detecting whether or not the 
checkbox was selected.
    return render(request, 'main/test.html')
```

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace?

Comment: @raydel sorry How do I get that?

Comment: I meant the error, could you post the complete error message?

Comment: Do you have `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` in your `MIDDLEWARE` in `settings.py`?

Comment: @RaydelMiranda I'm very sorry it just randomly worked with no errors now. Sorry for wasting your time. Turns out it needed a restart...

Comment: @Egor.L no problem, it happens, the "turn off - turn on"  or "stop-start" magical method is not so urban legend ;)

Comment: @RaydelMiranda Absolutely... :)

Comment: @RaydelMiranda Yep! Turning it on and off again works wonders! :)

Answer (score -1):

It will work, Just refresh your page or close your tab than try.

Comment: This answer needs elaboration on why just refreshing the page will fix the problem.

Comment: There is nothing to elaboration, In the code everything is good. I also check with the same code. If the answer needs to improve Egor. L should be asked for the same.

Comment: If yuor answer were an Egor. L private matter, you should e-mail him o text him, if you post here, your answer is for the community, and right now as it is, it is useless. The community won't learn anything from it. If you've checked the code, explain why the 403 and why worked after refreshing.